# ADO.NET number of rows that may be returned by a SQL Server select stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, ado.net

In C# using ado.net, how to know just the number of rows that may be returned by a SQL Server select stored procedure without returning the result set and without changing the stored procedure?

I don't want to read the data at all, I only want the number of rows because the load can consume a lot of memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd originally thought that .ExecuteNonQuery() would do it.  But since it doesn't work for SELECT statements, the DataReader will probably be your best (fastest) bet.

```
int count = 0;
using (var dr = new SqlDataReader(cmd)) {
   while (dr.Read()) count++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if u just don't want to load results, create another sql procedure that just returns `select Count(*) from etc...`

Comment: please give an example how to do that with sql server 2005 and MySP which have parameters @myPrm1,@myPrm2. thanks.

Comment: @Yaron  copy the existing SP and replace all of the fields in the select list with a single Count(*)

Comment: but i wrote in my question "without changing the store procedure".

Comment: u dont have to change the existing SP, just create another with diff name (something like **ur_sp_name + _rowcount**). leave the logic as in original SP, just replace fields in select with Count(*) (as Ben Robinson suggested)

Comment: thanks, but it's something to be done generally, because i need that feature for all the store procedures in my project that do fetch data.