# How can I get count of one select during selecting in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, count

I have a big select with many inner join and left join and select to select like:

```
SELECT 
    ( ... ) 
ORDER BY 
    Price
```

The question is for count of select am I must to run this select again ?

```
SELECT    
    COUNT( ... )  
ORDER BY 
    Price
```

Is there any easy way to run one times and get result of select and count of select ?

Here is my C# code with Entity Framework:

```
string strQuery = "....";

IQueryable<ProductDto> list = _entities.Database.SqlQuery<ProductDto>(strQuery).AsQueryable();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `select @@rowcount` to get the number of rows selected by  the previous statement as a second resultset, or use `SET @myOutputVar = @@ROWCOUNT` it as an output parameter of your stored procedure.

A few Q/A's here on StackOverflow that may also help

- [ADO.NET number of rows that may be returned by a SQL Server select stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6520007/ado-net-number-of-rows-that-may-be-return-by-an-sql-select-stored-procedure)
- [How to get number of rows using SqlDataReader in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1383315/how-to-get-number-of-rows-using-sqldatareader-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Can you show it on my query please , I didn't understand it

Comment: @dan - how do you execute your `select` is it a stored procedure? Is it called from .NET code?

Comment: @dan - have you seen this: [`CountAsync()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn177554(v=vs.113).aspx#M:System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbRawSqlQuery`1.CountAsync)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can try `select @@rowcount`.It Returns the number of rows affected by the last statement. If the number of rows is more than 2 billion, use `ROWCOUNT_BIG`.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms187316.aspx